# Actions on Google - Handle Timeout

Tags: bots, actions-on-google

If the Action on Google times out, for whatever reason, there doesn't seem to be a notification/request message sent notifying the webhook of this.

On Alexa platform, a SessionEnded message is sent to the webhook.

How can I know if the assistant has timed out?

Comment: It depends exactly what you mean by "timed out". Alexa and Assistant have different approaches to how the conversation flows. Can you give an example of a conversation and what the "timeout" sounds like?

Comment: On Alexa, if your request takes longer than 10 seconds, it sends a session ended message and the output is "the requested skill took to long". On Google Assistant, same experience after 5 seconds. However, no notification is sent to the webhook, enabling the cleaning up the conversation.

Comment: Is is that you need to offer the user some more information when he fails to respond? If so see here https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/reprompts

Comment: No, within my webhook, I maintain state, and have nested dialogs. It could happen that the session abruptly ends with the bot waiting for a response to the question. This is the stack that needs to reset. I can do this already. However, on Google Assistant, I'm not sure how to trigger it.

Comment: @NiteLordz did you find the solution?

Comment: @GiorgioRobino no there is no payload that is sent.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using node.js in your webhook, you can use the app.catch-method. It is used to catch all unhandled errors and then it is possible to send an appropriate message. Here is an example:

```
app.catch((conv,error) => {
console.error(error);
conv.close("Oops, something went wrong. Our developers are trying to solve this as quickly as possible.");
})
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Jorgé, did you test that erro catching way really catch a timeout event as requested? thanks

Comment: It's 6 months ago since I last worked with AoG so I'm sorry, I don't remember exactly anymore. I think it will show this message on your screen when your device has one, f.e. when you're talking to the GA on your smartphone.